# Can't get control back after execvp and wait()

Tags: c, shell, controls, fork, execvp

I'm coding a small shell that must execute my commands that I parse.

f is a char** like this: [ls][-la]
p is the same, used like this: [wc]
So I tried to pipe ls -la in wc.
My probleme is that when I execute "ls -la | wc && date", which works well for the pipe, my minishell get closed and it doesn't execute "date". I used the wait function to wait for it to finish but doesn't do anything. Looks like it's stuck and exit just after the 2nd execvp.

My arrays ends well by NULL.
ls -la | wc is well executed but I get back to bash after this. 
I've tried with execlp and execl but I think this is not the probleme considering that I need options of my first argument (ls + -la).
Could you help me please ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All forms of `exec` never return; they replace the currently running image with the indicated executable. The key word here is "replace".

The only circumstance in which the statement following a call to `exec*` gets executed is if the `exec` fails (for example, if it cannot find the executable).

Comment: Okay thanks I understand.
Do you have any idea why I don't get back to my shell but I get back to bash after my pipe ?

Comment: @user2145240: execution() never returns, so you never get back to your shell. Your shell has been replaced with `ls`, so when `ls` terminates, you are back to bash.

Comment: @user2145240: you can't unless you run *both* sides of the pipe in child processes. So you need a total of three processes: the shell, the utility on the left of the pipe, and the utility on the right of the pipe.

Comment: Yes that's what I've written. In the initial code, the first execvp was changed by my main function parsing the command and the second execvp get forked. The command works but I still don't get control back :(

Comment: @user2145240: exec doesn't create a process. fork creates a process. exec *replaces* the image of a process but it does *not* create a new process. Only fork creates a process. (Fork returns twice. exec never returns. Add up the returns :) )

Comment: Okay thanks a lot :) I've re-written my code and here it is : http://pastebin.com/i65R0HZP
It's funny because I get back to my shell, but after 1 command, it get closed and I get back to bash. Do I have to do a fork on my main loop of my shell ? (or around?)